# Cannot use format() and plus() in groovy anymore for ReadyAPI tests

Tags: javascript, groovy, date-format

Hi I have previously added days to date by for example data().plus(1).format('dd-mmm-yyyy') when writting groovy scripts for ReadyAPi
I have updated Ready API to version 3.3.2 and these stopped working for me. I can no longer use these methods. Is there any other way of getting the same result

```
def startdate = new Date().plus(1).format("yyyy-MM-dd")
log.info startdate
def enddate = new Date().plus(2).format('yyyy-MM-dd')
log.info enddate
```

Receiving following error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.Date.plus() is applicable for argument types: (Integer) values: [1] Possible solutions: parse(java.lang.String), is(java.lang.Object), split(groovy.lang.Closure), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait(), clone() error at line: 1
```

Please help. It has broken my test suite completely